# How to reposition the text of an input field in a way that it is no longer horizontally centred?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, position

I want to change the position of the text of the input to the top left corner. I have no success with what I tried and perhaps I might be calling the "input text" wrong...

Thanks in advance for helping this newbie!

I've tried both using relative and absolute positions as well as setting the input to margin:0 with no change at all.

```
 <form class="form-container">
   First name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
   <br>
   Last name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

```
.form-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;

  /* position: relative; */
}

.form-container input {
  height: 40px;

  /* position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; */

  /* margin: 0; */
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the text that a user enters? Or are you talking about showing placeholder instruction text to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this. Is that what you need?

```
`.form-container {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}

.form-container input[type=text] {
padding-bottom: 40px;
}`
```

Comment: Thanks @Viktoriia, this works. However, I'd like to ask something else if that's ok. Now I'm trying to break the lines so the text is not all written in the same line but it is not working either. I'm using  

.form-container input[type=text] {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

Comment: `input type="text"` can't have multiline input. You need to use a `<textarea></textarea>` instead.